# How do I edit a trigger function?

Tags: postgresql

How would I edit a trigger function in postgresql using `psql`? I have tried the using `\ef trigger_name` and every single time I try that it does not stick. Do I have to drop all of the triggers that refer to that trigger function before attempting to update it? I have been looking at the docs for a while and I did not find anything saying that I must to that? I have tried typing in the `CREATE OR REPLACE`... by hand into `psql` and that did not work.

Comment: Are you sure that the function you are editing is attached to the trigger you are testing? The name may look right, but the only way to know is by looking at the definition of the trigger itself.

Comment: @IMSoP I have been checking the definition of the trigger every time I have tried to update it.

Comment: The trigger function can be replaced without deleting the triggers that refer to it. Just `CREATE OR REPLACE` in `psql` should work. The problem may be that you do not have permissions to replace the trigger function (you need to be the owner of the function or a superuser). Try `\df+` on the trigger function to clear up that issue.

Comment: Any chance you have multiple definitions of the functions in different schema? `\df *.my_trigger_func_name`

Comment: @CraigRinger Checked that. Not what happened.

Comment: @Patrick I definitely am the owner of the function I am trying to replace.